# When to use SQL view over DTO

Tags: c#, sql

Hi first of all i just want to say that iam not a programmer yet. I started learning less than a year ago.

I have been thinking a bit and googled a bit but I can not find a concrete answer. I recently learned using SQL view. It is cool and it helped me complete my task. 
  If I have an old, poorly designed database, then views and DTO do wonders in my world. Mostly because it's the only way I know to work with data that are not dependent on each other but it still is? If I do a view with the data I want to work with, Entity Framework creates an entity of it. It feels like view and DTO's goes hand in hand a little bit, even though it's two completely different things. And then to my question.

When should I use view over DTO and vice versa?

(I am fully aware that this may be a stupid question since i didnt find anyone asking something similar!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sebastian,

Good on you for picking up the trade!

Regarding your question, there's sort of a false equivalency in it. Views are SQL constructs that allow us to provide a level of abstraction between the raw tables and the consumption of those tables. I've seen them used in very creative ways from predefining transforms on tables involving joins to other tables to a way of hiding certain tables from users all the way to providing an API of sorts to external consumers.

DTO's on the other hand are a coding related construct. They are generically any object that contains data shuttled between layers in an application which are generally devoid of any further business logic.

As such it's rather difficult to provide a straight-forward answer to your question.

I hope that helps,
Rob